# HttpClient GetStringAsync for Best Buy's website

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm working on a web scraping project, and I'm just trying to retrieve the full HTML of Best Buy products, but I'm not receiving any HTML response. Here's the code.

```cs
var url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/computer-cards-components/video-graphics-cards/abcat0507002.c?id=abcat0507002&qp=chipsetmanufacture_facet%3DChipset%20Manufacture~AMD";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
Console.WriteLine(html.Result);
```

So, this is all I'm doing, and Best Buy is the only website that times out and doesn't return HTML. I've tried this getting it for Amazon, eBay, and just other random websites, and I'm able to receive their HTML. Why is Best Buy timing out?

Could it be something with their robots.txt file? Do I need a specific User Agent? I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Chances are BestBuy doesn't want people crawling their website so they have anti-scraping measures, which could be anything from user agent validation to gateways like Cloudflare to WAFs.

Comment: Are you familiar with robots.txt? They have a list of user agents they allow/disallow. I'm just sure what to do about a user agent tho

Comment: IIRC `robots.txt` only matters if you personally write your code to honor it, it's not something that is automatically honored in any .NET functionality.

Comment: As @AlphaDelta said this is probably from anti-scraping measures. You can almost certainly get around this with a programmable browser like Selenium WebDriver (or using the API of a regular browser). The caveat is that this is slow in comparison to HttpClient.

Comment: Right, I'm currently using HTMLAgilityPack, but it's a little slow and I was exploring my options.